# Remove sub-folders without deleting files

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a directory below (**Before**). I would like to remove the Sub-folders and move the files to the Folder (**After**). How can I  archive it? Thanks

**Before**

```
Folder
 |-----Sub-folder1
 |        |------ fileA.txt
 |        |------ fileB.txt
 |-----Sub-folder2
          |------ fileC.txt
          |------ fileD.txt
```

**After**

```
Folder
 |------ fileA.txt
 |------ fileB.txt
 |------ fileC.txt
 |------ fileD.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with

```
mv **/* .
```

Note: this will overwrite files with the same name

This requires `shopt -s globstar` as Quasimodo pointed out:

> If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If the  pattern is followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories match.

Answer (score 1):

First move all the files in the subfolders to the current directory:

```
find . -type f -exec mv {} . \;
```

then remove the subdirectories

```
find . -type d -delete
```

Note: this will overwrite files with the same name

Comment: For performance, you can replace `\;` by `+`. For portability, `-delete` can be replaced by `-exec rmdir {} +`.

Comment: @Quasimodo, why with `+` we get a better performance? I didn't knew that.

Comment: Because it issues a minimal number of `mv` commands instead of one for each file. For more details, see [Using semicolon (;) vs plus (+) with exec in find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085156/using-semicolon-vs-plus-with-exec-in-find)